# Generate two negatively correlated data in excel

Tags: economics, correlation, covariance

Let's say that we have  two prices that are negatively correlated to each other, for instance  we have  price  $p_1$  and we want to generate  negatively correlated  price  $p_2$ with the following formula

$$p_2=k p_1+b\varepsilon$$

where  $k$ is correlation coefficient, $b$ is noise level and  $\epsilon$ is noise, but the problem is that for negative correlation $k$ must be less then zero right? but in this case price became negative which is non logical (every price must be   non-negative number), so what should I  do? Instead of

$$p_2=kp_1+b\varepsilon$$

should I use

$$p_2=a-kp_1+b \varepsilon \text{ ?}$$

where $a$ is intercept

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is $k$, not $b$, that must be negative to make the correlation negative. $\qquad$

Comment: ui sorry i will update

Comment: it was just typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use
$$p_2 = a+kp_1+b\epsilon,$$
where $k$ is negative, but this might still give you negative prices: If the noise $\epsilon$ happens to be so large in the negative direction that $a+kp_1+b\epsilon<0$, then you get a negative price.

This is not a feature of this particular model. It occurs also for the model $p_2 = kp_1+b\epsilon$, even when $k$ is positive, since the noise can take any value, and make the expression negative (if this often happens is another matter, it will depend on your choice of $a$ and $b$, but it will always happen with some positive probability).

What I've seen in practice is to cap the price at some minimum value, e.g. you can use a model
$$p_2 = \max(a+kp_1+b\epsilon,L),$$
where $L\geq 0$ is some lower bound that you do not want your price to fall below.

Comment: aa  you mean $L$  is positive number and  $k<0$ right?

Comment: @datodatuashvili yeah

Comment: but problem becames following : if  $k$ is less then zero, that means that in general $p_2$  became  also negative so formula max($k*p_1+b*\epsilon$,L) makes price  $p_2$ just constant

Comment: @datodatuashvili yes, and that is why your idea of adding $a$ is good.

Comment: ok thank you very much sir

Answer (score 1):

Adding a constant to $p_2$ will not change the correlation with $p_1$.  So, you can feel free do that to keep $p_2 > 0$.  However, $k$ is not exactly the correlation coefficient.

If $\sigma^2_1$ is the variance of $p_1$.  Then $k \sigma^2_1$ is the covariance of $p_1$,$p_2$.

$$\sigma^2_2 = k^2 \sigma^2_1 + \epsilon^2\sigma^2_b$$

$$\rho = \frac{k\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}$$

Comment: is it  for negative correlation or  general correlation coefficient? in other word  how to get $p_2$?

Comment: If k is negative then your correlation is negative and it k is positive your correlation is positive.